# How to fix hard disk bad sectors from terminal

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, hard-drive

I have a corrupted hard disk which I really much want to fix, but due to the situation we are in now I can not access physically my PC at office so I am ssh it from home, and I am wondering if there exist any solution to repair my harddisk. The output of my corrupted harddisk is given below:

```
NUC8i7HVK:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
? 1
Perform changes ? (y/n) y
/dev/sda1: 12 files, 1558/130812 clusters
```

I tried using ntfsfix tool but I got the following error

```
NUC8i7HVK:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
NTFS signature is missing.
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

Now I am afraid to experiment more since I can make hdd worst than it really is

Any solution or hint is really much appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: Is `/dev/sda1` the system partition for Ubuntu or is it the system partition for Windows? If Windows, you should use Windows to fix it.

Comment: It is for Ubuntu, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: If it is the Ubuntu system partition, then it can't be in NTFS format and `ntfsfix` won't fix it.

Comment: `ntfsfix` does not fix NTFS, it can only remove the dirty bit, cannot repair. Try `ntfsresize -vfi /dev/sda1`, it wont resize but check the drive. That is all you can do with Linux. The best way is to Boot Windows and run `chkdsk`

Comment: @cmak.fr If I use Windows to boot my machine and run the command you suggested, is it possible that when I remove Windows again and go back to Linux the disc will be fixed?